# $A\neq\bar A, A\neq$ int$(A)$ and $\partial A=\partial\bar A=\partial$ int$(A)$ in standard topology?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I've been trying to find a subset $A$ of real numbers in the standard topology that would fulfill the headline of this question i.e. $A\neq\bar A, A\neq$ int$(A)$ and $\partial A=\partial\bar A=\partial$ int$(A)$. I've been unlucky this far. I tried rationals, irrationals, integers and their complements. I also tried basic ideas like $(a,b), [a,b], (a,b)\cup \{c\}$ etc. with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. Can you help me?

Here $\partial$ means the boundary of the set defined as $\,\partial A=\bar A\setminus$ int$(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed $[a,b)$ This satisfies your requirements!

Answer (score 0):

$A=(0,1]$ is an example of that:

i) $\overline A=[0,1]\neq A$;

ii) $ \textrm{int}(A)=(0,1)\neq A$;

iii) $\partial A = \partial \overline A=\partial \, \textrm{int}(A)=\{0;1\} $